# Showing that a set is open in $C[0,1]$ with the maximum norm

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions $[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ with the max-norm $d(f,g) = \max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$ Show that $$A =\{f\in C[0,1] :f(x) >0, \forall x \in [0,1]\}$$ is open in $C[0,1].$

So we need to find $B(f,r) \subset A.$ The solution for this was that since $f$ is continuous there exists an $a \in [0,1]$ such that $f(a) \leqslant f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1].$ Then choosing $r= \frac{f(a)}{2}$ and picking  $g \in B(f, \frac{f(a)}{2})$ we only need to show that $g$ is positive. My question is that how did they come up with $r= \frac{f(a)}{2}$? Could this be shown some other way also since I wouldn't have figured that out on the fly...

Comment: Any positive number $r$ less than $f(a)$ works fine.

Comment: Why does it have to be neccesarily less than $f(a)$?

Comment: If you have $r > f(a)$ then $f(x)-f(a)$ is a function in the ball $B(f,r)$ which does not belong to $A$ because it vanishes when $x=a$.

Comment: Not sure I follow entirely. I can see that $f(x) - f(a)$ doesn't belong to $A$ when $x = a$, but how does choosing $r < f(a)$ help us avoid this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $r=f(a)$ also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f \in A$ has a minimum $f(a)>0$ assumed at the point $a \in [0,1]$.

Now, if $g$ is $r$-close to $f$ in the max-norm, this means that for all $x \in [0,1]$ we have $|f(x)-g(x)| \le \|f-g\| < r$. So we know already that all $f(x) \ge f(a) >0$ and we want to ensure that $g>0$ (i.e. $g \in A$). So if $r = f(a)$ we know that $g(x)\le 0$ is impossible because then $g(x) \le 0 < f(a) \le f(x)$ and then $|g(x)-f(x)| = f(x)-g(x) \ge f(a)$, and this contradicts $|f(x)-g(x)| < f(a)=r$. So $B(f,f(a))$ only contains $g$ that are $>0$.

Taking $r=\frac{f(a)}{2}$ only makes the proof slightly easier (an extra strict inequality). But the idea should be clear: $f$ lies above the line $y=f(a)$ and $g$ must be close to $f$ (i.e. $|g(x)-f(x)| < f(a)$ ) everywhere so cannot dip underneath the $x$-axis.

Comment: I can follow this, but the wording "if $g$ is $r$-close  to $f$ in the max-norm" that implies $|f(x)-g(x)| \le \|f-g\| < r$ has me a bit confused. What does this exactly mean? Is it neccessary for $g$ to be $r$-close?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Nate We want $B(f,r) \subseteq A$ so any $g$ that is $r$-close to $f$ (which means $\|f-g\| < r$) must lie in $A$.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to wrap my head around this! Is there a way I could perhaps visualize this? That might help me see the idea.

Comment: @Nate the last paragraph is a visualisation..(the graph of)  $f$ lies above the line $y=f(a)$ etc. $B(f,r)$ is just the set of all functions whose graph lies within an open band of width $r$ from the graph of $f$.

Comment: I'm trying to draw this. Should I think of $f$ and $g$ as a points here since $f$ is the center of the ball $B(f,r)$?